# How to start an independent program(in a separate console window) from another program in C on Windows?

Tags: c, windows, console-application, spawn, createprocess

I have a C application on Windows which needs to launch another application on some condition. I have been able to successfully launch the other application using the following line of code but the first application (the parent) and the new application (the child) are using the same window. I want them to have separate windows. How do I do it?

My code for launching the child application is:

```
    char *app_path = "path\\my_app.exe";
    char *app_arg = "arg";
    if (-1 == _spawnl(P_NOWAITO, app_path,app_arg,NULL))
    {
        printf_s("\nUnable to start the app. Error code %d", errno);
    }
    else
    {
        printf_s("\App started successfully.");
    }
```

N.B: the child app is not really a child app except for it being started by the "parent".

Comment: The same window?! How so? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Are these two applications both running in a console window?

Comment: @usr2564301 Yes they are.

Comment: Are you perhaps running it in a *debugger* for it to happen in the "*same window*"?...

Comment: Ok, so you mean the text output of both processes happen in the same console window. There is not much to do about it, but you could perhaps spawn `cmd.exe` with params  `/C path\\my_app.exe arg` instead of spawning `app.exe` directly.

Comment: @Ctx Yes the output of both is on the same console window. And i need them on separate windows.

Comment: @Ctx What does the "\C" stand for? Can you please give me the code line?

Comment: https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html

Comment: @Ctx Thanks for the link. I did it like this but the output is still the same. `char *cmd_args = "/C C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\my_app.exe app_arg";
 if ( -1==_spawnl(P_NOWAITO,"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",cmd_args,NULL))`

Comment: @George try `char *cmd_args = "/C start C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\my_app.exe app_arg";` instead and see if this works

Comment: @Ctx It solved it. Would you care to write it as an answer so that I can accept it as so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start your program like this:

```
char *cmd_args = "/C C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\my_app.exe app_arg";

if (-1 == _spawnl(P_NOWAITO, "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", cmd_args,NULL))
{
    printf_s("\nUnable to start the app. Error code %d", errno);
}
else
{
    printf_s("\App started successfully.");
}
```

`start` is a cmd-builtin, which will start the following command in a new window.

Comment: Your example doesn't actually use `start`.

Comment: It would be simpler to use `system` combined with `start`, which has the same effect to not wait on the child process and doesn't hard-code the path of cmd.exe (e.g. `ComSpec` may be a different shell, or `SystemRoot` may not be "C:\Windows").  For example: `system("start \"window title\" \"C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\my_app.exe\" app_arg")`. In general the executable path needs to be quoted, in which case we must include a window title due to the simplistic way that `start` parses its arguments.

Comment: Alternatively, choose the more complex route of calling `CreateProcess` directly, with the flag `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`.